# Realm Kotlin save data

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I am using `Realm` with `Kotlin` for a sample application. However, for whatever reason, the data is not being persisted after calling `commitTranscation()`. The `findAll()` method returns `size()` as 0 all the time.

WRITE

```
realm.beginTransaction()
  val userImage = UserImages()
  userImage.image = byteArray
  realm.commitTransaction()
```

READ

```
val userImage = realm.where(UserImages::class.java).findAll().last()
```

The above line always returns `size()` as 0 and crashes the app.

If it helps, the image property is a `byte array`.

What is the issue here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `insert` to actually save the new object. Something like:

```
val userImage = UserImages()
userImage.image = byteArray
realm.beginTransaction()
realm.insert(userImage)
realm.commitTransaction()
```

PS: you can use `executeTransaction` instead of the begin + end pair.
Like this:

```
realm.executeTransaction {
  realm.insert(userImage)
}
```

Comment: *facepalm*. That did work. Will accept the answer. Thank you.